# Target middle column from a 3 by 3 flex grid in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I wanted to add some marginLeft and marginRight to a FlatList grid of 3 by 3 but I'm having difficulties on trying to find the proper way to select the **middle column** items on a dynamic list by its current iteration index. (0->N)

The pattern of the middle column would be 1,4,7,10,13... so on. So it's a common difference of 3 between each number. The math formula for this would be `a + d(n−1)` according to a math page I found.

I need to add this logic within a FlatLists' renderItem, I was trying to use `index % 2` or `index % 3` but I couldn't get a nice result from it.

This is my code:

```
         <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={ () => this._handleImagePress(this.state.pictures, index - 1) }
            style={ [
                styles.photoItem,
                (index % 2) ? styles.pixelMarginRight : '']
            }>
            <FastImage
                style={ styles.image }
                source={{
                    uri: item.url,
                    priority: FastImage.priority.high,
                }}
                resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.cover}
            />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
```

Any idea on how can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: this point `style={ [
                styles.photoItem,
                (index % 2) ? styles.pixelMarginRight : ''"]`  should be  `style={ [
                styles.photoItem,
                (index % 2  == 0) ? styles.pixelMarginRight : '']`  the reason is because you need the expression to evaluate to true or false so that the ternary operator can work correctly

Comment: yea, it's kinda better but still, this way is targeting odd indexes only, though. And i was looking for a specific pattern which includes both odd and even. That's why if i wanna go this way, i need a better logic rather than odd/even number. It's a difference of 3 on each iteration, that's why it goes like 1,4,7,10, ...

Comment: Ok in that case your logic will be something like the following. ` ((index + 2)%3)  ==0? styles.pixelMarginRight : '' `

Comment: Let me try to explain why I think its going to be correct that way in a post

Comment: Awesome! It works like a charm. Thanks man. Create a post and i will mark it as solved :)

Comment: I have added the explanation for why I chosed the values specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your formula, `Tn = a+ d(n-1)` is the formula for getting terms in an arithmetic progression so if we assume that the `index` are the actual terms which vary as you said then, first term `a = 1`, common difference `d = 3` since we know Tn = index, then all we need do is look for n from the formula and using the raw formula, we we factorize n, ie move a to left side of the equation we have `Tn - a = dn -d`  if we again move -d to the left of the equation we have `Tn-a+d = dn` now we only need to substitute with the real values which we identified above which leads to (index - 1+3) = 3n 
`(index +2) = 3n` we can then conclude that for index to be a term in the said arithmetic progression then n most be a positive real number  which can only happend if the remainder when the expression `(index+2) % 3` is zero.